# Is there a way modify the default comment tags per language like you can in Sublime Text

Tags: visual-studio-code, comments

Is there a way to customize comments per language as you can do in SublimeText? I would like to add my initials to my comments.

Comment: You should tag this under VS Code.  An rephrase as is there a way to add custom append to VS Code comments, I believe you should be using a commercial code tracking package that tracks what user modified what line of code.  There could be a way to program that to a custom shortcut key combo to insert what you want, each time rather than typing it.

Comment: Remove text that wasn't 100% related to the question.